How to get the current filename being processed in Vector Remap Language?
I'm using Vector.dev and the vector remap language.
I have an event in error.log
//file: error.log
{
    "message": "Hello world",
    "foo": "bar",
}

I would like the output to have the current file being processed added to the output.  Any idea how to do that?
//output
{
    "message": "Hello world",
    "foo": "bar",
    "filename": "error.log"  //Add the filename to the output
}

